# HTML Div class background stays blank

Tags: html, css

So, I've been trying to get to know CSS and HTML a bit better. But whenever I try to set the background-color of a div(class) it just stays white. I hope one of you out there can help me. Thanks (I've tried adding a code snippet, but it wouldnt let me)

```css
.navigator {
    background-color: #FF00FF;
    background-size: 150%;
}
 
.pagina {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 120px;
}
 
.informatie {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigator">
    <div class="pagina">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle=
            "dropdown" id="menu1" type="button">Pagina's <span class=
            "caret"></span></button>
            <ul aria-labelledby="menu1" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#" role="menuitem">Pagina 1</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#" role="menuitem">Pagina 2</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#" role="menuitem">Pagina 3</a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider" role="presentation"></li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#" role="menuitem">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="informatie">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle=
            "dropdown" id="menu1" type="button">Informatie <span class=
            "caret"></span></button>
            <ul aria-labelledby="menu1" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#" role="menuitem">informatie 1</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#" role="menuitem">informatie 2</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#" role="menuitem">informatie 3</a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider" role="presentation"></li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#" role="menuitem">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, welcome. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try adding some padding or height to your div, the height of a div is by default 0.

Comment: Thanks Rick, that helped!

Comment: @Rick the floats of the child elements of `.navigator` need to be cleared. Doing so will allow the parent element to re-size naturally with the size of the child elements. Setting `padding` and `height` does not natrually wrap around the child elements. Each time the content size changes for the floated child elements the padding/height would need to be re-calculated. It would also require additional CSS for a responsive design. Use a [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

Comment: @hungerstar You're right about the clearfix ;) I didn't notice the float.

Answer (score 0):

use CSS flexBox

```css
.navigator {
  background-color: #FF00FF;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigator">
  <div class="pagina">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="menu1" type="button">Pagina's <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul aria-labelledby="menu1" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#" role="menuitem">Pagina 1</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#" role="menuitem">Pagina 2</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#" role="menuitem">Pagina 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="divider" role="presentation"></li>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#" role="menuitem">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="informatie">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="menu1" type="button">Informatie <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul aria-labelledby="menu1" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#" role="menuitem">informatie 1</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#" role="menuitem">informatie 2</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#" role="menuitem">informatie 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="divider" role="presentation"></li>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#" role="menuitem">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer but they might want to see an example and be told why it's happening (height 0 etc)

Comment: Explanation is always good. Not everyone that comes along this post will understand the ins and outs, just like the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The element `.navigator` has child elements that are floated. When you float elements they are taken out of the normal document flow and do not take up any space. `.pagina` and `.informatie` are both floated so `.navigator` has no height and hence no background color.

Add a [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) to the parent element with floated child elements.

```css
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: " ";
  /* 1 */
  display: table;
  /* 2 */
}
.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}
.navigator {
  background-color: #FF00FF;
  background-size: 150%;
}
.pagina {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 120px;
}
.informatie {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigator cf">
  <div class="pagina">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="menu1" type="button">Pagina's <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul aria-labelledby="menu1" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#" role="menuitem">Pagina 1</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#" role="menuitem">Pagina 2</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#" role="menuitem">Pagina 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="divider" role="presentation"></li>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#" role="menuitem">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="informatie">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="menu1" type="button">Informatie <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul aria-labelledby="menu1" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#" role="menuitem">informatie 1</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#" role="menuitem">informatie 2</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#" role="menuitem">informatie 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="divider" role="presentation"></li>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#" role="menuitem">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```